# correctly displays a seekbar in custom adapter

Tags: android

I have a list in which each element on a player. When I click on "start" and a song starts playing strip seekbar starts moving. when click on the "stop" the song stops playing and the strip stops. But if while moving the strip I scroll list and it goes off the screen, it starts to move another strip that is on the same position in the visible area of the screen.

```
public class RecordAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    private ArrayList<RecordBean> recordBeans;
    private final Handler handler = new Handler();
    private Context ctx;
    private int global_position;

       ...
    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View view = convertView;
        final ViewHolder holder;
        if (convertView == null) {
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.recorditem, parent, false);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.date = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.recordate);
            holder.seekBar = (SeekBar) view.findViewById(R.id.seekBar);
            holder.start = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btnStart);
            holder.stop = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btnStop);

            view.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
        }
        holder.date.setText(" " + recordBeans.get(position).getDate());
        holder.start.setTag(position);
        holder.stop.setTag(position);
        holder.seekBar.setTag(position);
        holder.seekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(final SeekBar seekBar, final int i, boolean b) {
                if (b && (Integer)seekBar.getTag()==global_position) {
                    mediaPlayer.seekTo(i);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
            }
        });
        holder.start.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                releaseMP();
                try {
                    mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
                    mediaPlayer.setDataSource(recordBeans.get((Integer) v.getTag()).getFile());
                    mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
                    mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
                            mediaPlayer.start();
                            global_position = position;
                            holder.start.setTextColor(Color.RED);
                            holder.seekBar.setMax(mediaPlayer.getDuration());
                            startPlayProgressUpdater(holder.seekBar,holder.start);
                        }
                    });
                    mediaPlayer.prepareAsync();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                if (mediaPlayer == null) {
                    return;
                }
                mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
                        Log.d("LOG_TAG", "onCompletion");
                        holder.start.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
                    }
                });
            }
        });

        holder.stop.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (mediaPlayer == null)
                    return;
                if ((Integer) v.getTag() == global_position) {
                    mediaPlayer.stop();
                }
            }
        });
        return view;
    }

    private void releaseMP() {
        if (mediaPlayer != null) {
            try {
                mediaPlayer.release();
                mediaPlayer = null;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    private static class ViewHolder {
        TextView date;
        SeekBar seekBar;
        Button start;
        Button stop;
    }

    public void startPlayProgressUpdater(final SeekBar seek, final Button start) {
        seek.setProgress(mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition());
        if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
            Runnable notification = new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    startPlayProgressUpdater(seek,start);
                }
            };
            handler.postDelayed(notification, 1000);
        } else {
            mediaPlayer.pause();
            seek.setProgress(0);
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT:

I added geter and seter in recordBean

```
 public int getSeekPos() {
            return SeekPos;
        }

        public void setSeekPos(int seekPos) {
            SeekPos = seekPos;
        }
```

and

```
holder.seekBar.setProgress(recordBeans.get(position).getSeekPos());
        holder.date.setText(" " + recordBeans.get(position).getDate());
```

and

```
@Override
            public void onProgressChanged(final SeekBar seekBar, final int i, boolean b) {
                if (b && (Integer)seekBar.getTag()==global_position) {
//                    mediaPlayer.seekTo(i);
                    recordBeans.get(position).setSeekPos(i);
                }
            }
```

but I think it left something extra in my code

Comment: Check : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26798716/app-crashes-onplaying-audio-in-adapter-of-listview-second-time/26799487#26799487

Comment: You've already answered in another question. could share the code? Here's a link to where you yovopros me answered http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26644851/display-problems-seekbar-in-custom-adapter

Answer (score 0):

The list item is being recycled when it leaves the screen.
You could try to call this in getView:

```
holder.seekBar.clearFocus();
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a tricky process, but you can do this in the following way, as I have seen that you have created a List of `RecordBean` class. So what you can do is you have to create a Getter Setter in `RecordBean` for storing the position of you `SeekBar` like:

```
public void setSeekPos(int pos) {
    this.pos = pos;
}

public int getSeekPos() {
    return pos;
}
```

In your adapter below the line
`holder.date.setText(" " + recordBeans.get(position).getDate());`

set the progress of seekBar like this:  `holder.seekBar.setProgress(recordBeans.get(position).getSeekPos());`

and inside the `onProgressChanged` add the following line `recordBeans.get(position).setSeekPos(i);`

This will resolve your issue.

Please let me know if it's working or not.

Thanks

Comment: Just remove the if statement in onProgressChange

Comment: I changed the method for if 

 @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(final SeekBar seekBar, final int i, boolean b) {
                if (b && (Integer)seekBar.getTag()==global_position) {
                    mediaPlayer.seekTo(i);
                }
                recordBeans.get(position).setSeekPos(i);
            }

Comment: Remove if (b && (Integer)seekBar.getTag()==global_position) {
//                    mediaPlayer.seekTo(i);
                    recordBeans.get(position).setSeekPos(i);
                } and only add recordBeans.get(position).setSeekPos(i);

Comment: I was very confused in the code. Could you remove the excess and give an example of how it should be? I will be very grateful. this problem for several days ((((

Comment: I think that the problem may be even in this method. but do not know how to change it startPlayProgressUpdater(holder.seekBar,holder.start);

Comment: @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(final SeekBar seekBar, final int i, boolean b) {
                recordBeans.get(position).setSeekPos(i);
            }
does not work(((