# I can not stop and release the player in android

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, android-seekbar

Please explain to me how to properly use the player + `SeekBar`. using the method of stopping is not an error, but the program crashes when starting and stopping a few songs. using realase error output
error

I run the player and seekbar:

```
holder.start.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
  @Override
  public void onClick(View v) {
    releaseMP();
    try {
      global_position = position;
      mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
      mediaPlayer.setDataSource(recordBeans.get(global_position).getFile());
      mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
      mediaPlayer.prepareAsync();
      mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
          holder.seekBar.setMax(mediaPlayer.getDuration());
          mediaPlayer.start();
          startPlayProgressUpdater(holder.seekBar);
        }
      });
    } catch (IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
    mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
      @Override
      public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
        mediaPlayer.release();
        mediaPlayer = null;
      }
    });
  }
});
```

**error points to a `string`**

```
recordBeans.get(global_position).setSeekPos(mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition());
```

Start the player and upgrade method seekbar:

```
public void startPlayProgressUpdater(final SeekBar seekBar) {
  if (mediaPlayer != null) {
    recordBeans.get(global_position).setSeekPos(mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition());
  } else {
    recordBeans.get(global_position).setSeekPos(0);
  }
  if ((Integer) seekBar.getTag() == global_position) {
    seekBar.setProgress(recordBeans.get(global_position).getSeekPos());
    }
    if (mediaPlayer != null) {
      Runnable notification = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
          startPlayProgressUpdater(seekBar);
        }
      };
      handler.postDelayed(notification, 1000);
    }
  }
```

Stop button:

```
holder.stop.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

  @Override
  public void onClick(View v) {
    if ((Integer) v.getTag() == global_position && mediaPlayer != null) {
      mediaPlayer.release();
      mediaPlayer = null;
    }
  }
});
```

When `seekbar` comes to an end:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.example.MANAGMENT.fragments.adapters.RecordAdapter$4.run(RecordAdapter.java:165)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Check : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26798716/app-crashes-onplaying-audio-in-adapter-of-listview-second-time/26799487#26799487

Comment: you give me 3 times this link. it does not help me in any way. there is no matter what I need.

Comment: Okay so this mean you have ask same question 3 times...

Comment: this means that the decision that you are giving me is not related to my problem.
read carefully my question

Comment: then why you ask same question again again ?

Comment: because to me, no one can help. and the issue is not solved yet. I am suffering for several days (((

Comment: Ask many times same question is not ri8 solution for your problem.

Comment: I do not want to argue with you. I will ask and seek a solution not found yet. you could help me if you look at the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying){
      mediaPlayer.release;
   }
```

wherever u r releasing media player

Comment: (y) happy programming